# Does 'R' or 'dplyr' have a limit in the number of decimal places it uses in calculations?

Tags: dplyr

This may be trivial, so apologies in advance if it is. I searched for similar questions, however, all the ones I came across focused on changing/rounding the number of outputted decimal places in R.

I am using the mutate function from dplyr to manipulate an output from a model created in R, and noticed that a column that was created based on this output does not equal '0' like it should.

There may be another reason for the discrepancy, but based on the number of decimal places in the outputted data, I get the feeling that this might be a limitation in R or dplyr.

Does anyone know if such a restriction exists, and if there is a way to change it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you're talking about doubles, then it's not so much that it has a limit on the number of decimal places, but more that it has a limit on the accuracy of the calculations. Doubles are floating point numbers, which only cover some numbers, and when you get really far above or really far below 0, the number of numbers they cover can be not many

Comment: e.g. in R, `((2^500)+1) - (2^500) = 0`